# Requesting HTTPS URL from insecure server?

Tags: security

Let's say that server **A** (HTTP), makes requests to an endpoint at server **B** (HTTPS) with a URL beginning with `https://`.

Is there any additional security to gain by enabling SSL on server **A**? Or is the connection secure as-is, being that the endpoint is secure?

Comment: Communication between clients and A is not secure. Is that a problem?

Comment: In this context, I am only concerned with the communication between A and B - not with A's clients.